# Building and deploying NextJS container app with App Insights instrumentation doesn't work

Tags: docker, next.js, dockerfile, azure-application-insights, instrumentation

I'm trying to implement instrumentation for my nextjs 13.4.19 application (using pages directory). Everything works when running the application with `npm run dev` in my local environment. However, when trying to build the app to the docker image and deploy to production environment, it seems like something goes wrong and the application can't even start itself. I wasn't able to debug the reason.

I'm using instrumentation hook as described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation

My `next.config.js` contains `output: "standalone"` for the building process. I'm using the docker file from the nextjs example. The whole code of a very simple application can be found here:

https://github.com/kubop/nextjs-appinsights-issue/tree/master

Perhaps, my definition of dockerfile is wrong? When trying to deploy the docker image to Azure container app the logs contain something like this:
`startup probe failed: connection refused`

When I'm trying to run the container locally, using `docker run -p 3000 myapp` I receive `- ready started server on 127.0.0.1:3000, url: http://127.0.0.1:3000` but when trying to reach the url, I get:

**`localhost`**`didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the problem. I don't know why, but for some reason in my dockerfile I had `ENV HOSTNAME localhost`. Changing it to `ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"` fixed my issue.